# How to find part of the code which creates Anonymous private memory mapped region

Tags: memory, c++, mmap

I'm analyzing `/proc/pid/smaps` output for C++ process and I find large number of private memory mapped regions. Number of memory mapped regions keep growing based on the traffic.

Is there a way I can track which part of the code creates memory blocks ?. I tried `strace -p <pid>`, But could not get to the stack while it is created.

```
00-7fcea0000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
Size:              65536 kB
Rss:               65520 kB
Pss:               65520 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:     65520 kB
Referenced:        65520 kB
Anonymous:         65520 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Locked:                0 kB
VmFlags: rd wr mr mw me nr sd
7fcea4000000-7fcea8000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
Size:              65536 kB
Rss:               65516 kB
Pss:               65516 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:     65516 kB
Referenced:        65516 kB
Anonymous:         65516 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Locked:                0 kB
VmFlags: rd wr mr mw me nr sd
7fceac000000-7fceb0000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
Size:              65536 kB
Rss:               65524 kB
Pss:               65524 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:     65524 kB
Referenced:        65524 kB
Anonymous:         65524 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Locked:                0 kB
                                                                                                                                                                                          7fceb4000000-7fceb8000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
Size:              65536 kB
Rss:               65528 kB
Pss:               65528 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:     65528 kB
Referenced:        65528 kB
Anonymous:         65528 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Locked:                0 kB
VmFlags: rd wr mr mw me nr sd
7fcebc000000-7fcec0000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
Size:              65536 kB
Rss:               65516 kB
Pss:               65516 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:     65516 kB
Referenced:        65516 kB
Anonymous:         65516 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Locked:                0 kB
VmFlags: rd wr mr mw me nr sd
7fcec4000000-7fcec8000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
Size:              65536 kB
Rss:               65504 kB
Pss:               65504 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:     65504 kB
Referenced:        65504 kB
Anonymous:         65504 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
                                                                                                                                                                                          332,20         2%
```